# Eclipse is throwing an error when using Dreamweaver CS6 Site files in Eclipse Android PhoneGap Project

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, dreamweaver, phonegap-plugins

How to import the generated Dreamweaver PhoneGap Site files into Eclipse IDE for Android Platform.

I am currently using Dreamweaver CS6 Trail Version to build a PhoneGap application.

I copied all the files generated in the Dreamweaver site folder and pasted it in assets/www folder.

It worked initially for a hello world application and displayed correctly in the Android Emulator, but now my PhoneGap application with 5 HTML pages works just fine in Dreamweaver CS6, but its not working on Eclipse.

When i try to run the application it shows a blank white screen for like 2 mins and then a black screen for 30 seconds and then throws an error

```
"E/Web Console(302): SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent. at file:///android_asset/www/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js:70".
```

I tried adding try catch block for a function present in .js file, but did not work out for me. I am still getting the same error.

Am i doing something wrong ? or Is it the reason that both are different ways of developing Phonegap Apps ?

Answer (score 0):

That error message suggests this is a Content Security Policy problem. Is your site making cross-domain XHRs or other CSP-unfriendly activities?

This probably has nothing to do with Dreamweaver as such. Also possibly a problem with the Phonegap URL whitelist.

Comment: I am just building a simple PhoneGap Application with 5 UI Screens written in a single index.html. I am not aware of Cross-domain XHRs or other CSP-unfriendly activities. Currently using Dreamweaver CS6 to make my HTML, CSS, JavaScript files and then trying to build Android eclipse project out of it.